# how do i set the etag using the HttpResponseMessage object in mvc 4 web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a bit of a  helper class in my Web API project so I'm kind of stuck using HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage, or at least so it would seem. I've generated the eTag that I want to send back in the HttpResponseMessage, but I'm not sure where to add it to the object as everything has changed since WCF where I would simply use CheckConditionalRetrieve();

My question is, I have my eTag... lol... where do I put it using HttpResponseMessage???

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel kinda silly. I've been looking for hours and just ran across it randomly. There are two Headers fields available in the request and response objects.

```
response.Headers
```

and

```
request.Content.Headers
```

The Etag property is in the top level Headers:

```
response.Headers.ETag
```

so my final code ended up being:

```
_response.Headers.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue(eTag);
```